# Why Upgrading to Alpinejs 3.2 menu does noes not work?

Tags: alpine.js

In Laravel 8 / Alpinejs 2.8 app I had toggle menu like

```
<!--Toggle button (hidden on large screens)-->
<button
    @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
    type="button"
    class="block lg:hidden px-2 text-gray-500 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white"
    :class="{ 'transition transform-180': isOpen }"
>
    <svg
        class="h-6 w-6 fill-current"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    >
        <path
            x-show="isOpen"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
            d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
        />
        <path
            x-show="!isOpen"
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
        />
    </svg>
</button>

<!--Menu-->
<div
    class="w-full flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto"
    :class="{ 'block shadow-3xl': isOpen, 'hidden': !isOpen }"
    @click.away="isOpen = false"
    x-show.transition="true"
>
    <ul
        class="pt-6 lg:pt-0 list-reset lg:flex justify-end flex-1 items-center"
    >
        <li class="mr-3">
```

and it worked ok.
Upgrading to Alpinejs 3.2 modified

```
@click.away="isOpen = false"
```

with @click.away="isOpen = false"
with

```
@click.outside="isOpen = false"
```

and

```
x-show.transition="true"
```

into

```
x-show="true"
x-transition
```

but after that drop down menu is not visible at all.

Why so and how it can be fixed?

**MODIFIED # 1:**

1. If to change x-show="isOpen" for menu then yes, on small devices menu works as expected, but
   on big devices it is not visible at all
2. I need somehow to set init value to true on big devices. Condition :

   ```
      x-show="isOpen"
      md:x-show="true"
      x-transition
   ```

does not work

3. I think I can use package https://github.com/jenssegers/agent to get this value depending on current device.
   Are there better decision?
4. Could you please explain how devtools were usefull in this debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check it in devtools it is actually works as expected when you toggle `isOpen` state. The problem is when you click button it is also considered as `click.away` out of menu. I'll suggest to set this click on a parent element. Also I change menu settings - x-show set to `isOpen` like `x-show="isOpen"` and toggle statement will handle visibility of element with Tailwind's `visible` class

```
<div
   x-data="{ isOpen: false }"
   @click.outside="isOpen = false"
>
    <button
          @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
          type="button"
          class="block lg:hidden px-2 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none"
          :class="{ 'transition transform-180': isOpen }"
      >
        <svg
          class="w-6 h-6 fill-current"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
        <path
          x-show="isOpen"
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
          d="M18.278 16.864a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.414l-4.829-4.828-4.828 4.828a1 1 0 0 1-1.414-1.414l4.828-4.829-4.828-4.828a1 1 0 0 1 1.414-1.414l4.829 4.828 4.828-4.828a1 1 0 1 1 1.414 1.414l-4.828 4.829 4.828 4.828z"
         />
         <path
           x-show="!isOpen"
           fill-rule="evenodd"
           d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
         />
      </svg>
   </button>

   <!--Menu-->
   <div
       class="flex-grow w-full lg:flex shadow-3xl lg:items-center lg:w-auto"
       :class="[ isOpen ? 'visible' : 'unvisible' ]"
       x-show="isOpen"
       x-transition
    >
    <ul
     class="items-center justify-end flex-1 pt-6 lg:pt-0 list-reset lg:flex"
    >
      <li class="mr-3"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="mr-3"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED # 1

Comment: Oh I see ypu need to always show menu on desktop and toggle on mobile that what I've missed. Check is it mobile or not you can with `window.innerWidth < 640` for example. It will return true on every device which screen width less than 640px. Change `x-show` to `x-show="window.innerWidth > 640 ? true : isOpen"`. That mean always show on devices large than 640px and toggle visibility on smaler. About devtools- there is an extension for browser called alpinejs - it shows states and components