# Alpinejs & tailwind navbar | toggling open on screen size

Tags: frontend, navbar, tailwind-css, phoenix-framework, alpine.js

I have a basic set up for a toggleable navbar using alpinejs and tailwind - however I want to have the navbar automatically toggle to !open (closed) when the screensize is less than 'md:' in tailwind or < 768px, and toggle to open (open) when the screensize is greater than 'md:' in tailwind or > 768px.

Currently - the navbar closes at each page load - which isn't bad - I just want to understand how to make it toggleable in the way described above.

Wondering what the recommended approach to this is - since this is my first time using alpine.

A summation of my code can be found below:

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="navclasses">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open" class="buttonclasses"></button> (left justified)
  <div x-show="open">
    <ul>
      <li>links to other pages in site</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266675/why-upgrading-to-alpinejs-3-2-menu-does-noes-not-work/68268028#68268028) question is what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

approach can be found below:

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="navclasses">
  <button x-on:click="open = !open" class="buttonclasses"></button> (left justified)

X <div x-show="open"> X - removed this line
  
<div x-show=window.innerWidth > 767 ? true: open">

    <ul>
      <li>links to other pages in site</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```